# Защита памяти от перехвата

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Есть серверное .NET приложение. Архитектура x64.

Есть подозрение, что данные, которые обрабатывает приложение перехватываются сотрудниками ДЦ. Возможно как либо защитить их в самой системе от перехвата? Например методами класса ProtectedMemory? Поможет ли это?

Comment: а вы эти данные по сети получаете?

Comment: @tym32167 Сетевая часть обернута в TLS 1.2, используется стандартная обертка SslStream над Crypto API винды.

Comment: то есть сторудникам ДЦ достаточно организовать MITM, а не копаться в дампах ваших процессов.

Comment: @tym32167 там еще внутри TLS идет дополнительная криптография. Данные идут в сериализованном виде. Так что думаю врятли через сетевую часть перехватывают.

Comment: Тогда может и имеет смысл смотреть в сторону ProtectedData и ProtectedMemory, ну и/или сменить хостинг

Comment: @tym32167, пока слабо представляю как обернуть в них те же List, Dictionary и прочее. Видимо надо будет писать свои реализации. Но главный вопрос - помогут ли  ProtectedData и ProtectedMemory от перехвата?

Comment: я не спец, просто предположу, что вы не сможете просто так обернуть что то, вам придется сериализовать данные в массив байт и шифровать уже массив. Шифрование использует ключи уровня ОС или юзера, потому, кмк, если сотрудники ДЦ реально профи и уже в курсе типа шифрования и имеют админский доступ к машине и/или вашему юзеру и могут вашу виртуалку склонировать и у них дофига времени свободного и ваши данные того вообще стоят, то может что то у них и получится.